# How to define the connection between pallets?

Tags: staking, balances

In susbtrate, how to use a component of a pallet in other pallets, how to refer them?
For example,

- How is the Balance in `pallet-balances` used in `pallet-staking`? Or in a custom pallet template?
- And What is the function of selecting next authorities selection?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by `change criteria of next authorities selection`

Comment: @ShubhamGupta I edited the question. I want to find the function where the next set of authorities are picked?

Comment: updated my answer do accept it if it solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

> how to use a component of a pallet in other pallets, how to refer
> them?

To call functionalities or use storages or types of one to another, you need to do coupling of pallets, either loose coupling of tight coupling. For coupling of pallets you can refer to https://docs.substrate.io/build/pallet-coupling/

> And What is the function of selecting next authorities selection?

The election of authorities is defined in [election-porvider-support](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/tree/master/substrate/frame/election-provider-support), in that you can check [onchain.rs](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/substrate/frame/election-provider-support/src/onchain.rs) file that contains the logic for how onchain election occurs here https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/32c047af388984f8cae432359d398ed895c758e1/substrate/frame/election-provider-support/src/onchain.rs#L99-L146